# Comparing two set of data and extract the most information

Tags: multivariate-analysis, software

I have a dataset from RNA sequencing of 4 different regions and comparing 2 groups.

I would like to be able to compare the average expression of each group for each gene, however, I don't know the optimal multi-parametric tests allowing me to generate the most information.

My idea was to carry out a correlation study (with correlation matrices comparing one group with the other), a possible PCA test?

Do you know of any software suitable for such studies? And ideally, other multi-parametric tests that would be relevant?

Thank you for your help !